# Foreach fetch response JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm currently working on a project in JavaScript where I must fetch the tickets to display them. So basically here I'm fetching the URL followed by an API Key, JSON the response then want to push the result into a global variable. Here is the code:

```js
//var datas used in fetch
var colors = { 10: "#33cc33", 20: "#ffcc00", 30: "#ff0066", 40: "##ff0000" }
var posts = [];
//query the ticket API
fetch(process.env.ticket_url.concat(apikey))
    //transform the response into json datas 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        //if the Key is wrong
        if (res.status == 401) {
            message.channel.send("Your API key is not valable, please set a valable one with !setinfo command followed by your key");
        }
        //if the Key is valid
        else {
            res.forEach(element => {
                var post = {};
                post[id] = element[id];
                post[color] = colors[priority_id];
                post[title] = element[title];
                post[description] = element[description];
                console.log(post)
                posts.push(post);
            })
        }
        // code to handle the error
    }).catch(err => {});
```

However, as you can see I was waiting to receive as much post as my API result me thanks to the `console.log(post)`, but I receive nothing.
I wanted to add that.

```js
var colors = { 10: "#33cc33", 20: "#ffcc00", 30: "#ff0066", 40: "##ff0000" }
        var posts = [];
        //query the ticket API
        fetch(process.env.ticket_url.concat(apikey))
            //transform the response into json datas 
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                //if the Key is wrong
                if (res.status == 401) {
                    message.channel.send("Your API key is not valable, please set a valable one with !setinfo command followed by your key");
                }
                //if the Key is valid
                else {
                    console.log(res)
                }
                // code to handle the error
            }).catch(err => { });
```

Is returning the expected response under this format :

```json
[ .
  .
  .,
  {
    id: 222610,
    title: '456',
    description: '== what is the issue? ==\n\n== enter steps to reproduce ==',
    user_id: 808,
    company_id: 76,
    assigned_to_id: 805,
    status_id: 60,
    priority_id: 30,
    ticket_queue_id: 69,
    rating: null,
    rated_on: null,
    created_on: '2020-08-14T18:24:37.000Z',
    updated_on: '2020-08-14T18:24:54.000Z',
    status_changed_on: '2020-08-14T18:24:54.000Z',
    solved_on: '2020-08-14T18:24:54.000Z',
    assigned_on: '2020-08-14T18:24:39.000Z',
    created_from: 0,
    ticket_type_id: null,
    cc: '',
    legacy_id: null,
    first_assigned_on: '2020-08-14T18:24:39.000Z',
    user_attention_id: null,
    due_on: '2020-08-29T11:59:59.000Z',
    scheduled_on: '2020-08-28T11:59:59.000Z',
    is_attention_required: true,
    ticket_form_id: 425,
    resolution_id: 1
  }
]
```

So the question is: I don't know what is wrong in this code, can you help me to figure it out because I'm searching for times but can't figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the keys - id, title ... in quotes. That is post["id"] = element["id"] and so on.

Comment: Well that solved my problem. I really thought that was a fetch problem but actually i'm dumb. Thanks mate :D